# rsync failed to set permissions for a local copy ("Function not implemented")

Tags: permissions, rsync, backup, file-copy

There are lots of similar questions out there, but none seems to address my problem: every time, the culprit is a legitimate permission issue, or an incompatible filesystem, none of which makes any sense here.

I'm transferring a file locally, on an ext4 filesystem, using rsync. A minimal example is:

```bsh
cd /tmp
touch blah
mkdir test
rsync -rltDvp blah test
```

which returns the error:

```
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/tmp/test/.blah.Gyvvbw": Function not implemented (38)
```

and the files have different permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ted ted 0 Sep 29 15:49 blah
-rw------- 1 ted ted 0 Sep 29 15:49 test/blah
```

I'm running rsync as user `ted` and the filesystem is ext4, so it should support permissions just fine. Here is the corresponding line from `df -Th`:

```
Filesystem                  Type        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/c--3px--vg-root ext4        936G  395G  494G  45% /
```

I'm running rsync 3.2.3 protocol version 31 on Debian Sid, kernel 5.10.0-6-amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP wrote,

> `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, which apparently upgraded `rsync` (to version 3.2.3-8), fixed the problem.

The error was presumably caused by to [a change to `lchmod` and `fchmodat` in the GNU C library](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=994543).